# Mutual Funds Investment advice needed for beginner

Tags: india, mutual-funds, debt, dividends, equity

I am planning to start investing in mutual funds now. I am a beginner and young(28). I plan on doing investments as a lump sum and SIP. I plan to invest 5 lakhs via lump sum now and SIP of 20k per month for next 3 years starting this month. I plan to diversify my investments across multiple types of funds by taking moderate risk.

Lumpsum Strategy: Invest 50% across hybrid funds (Kotak Dynamic Bond Fund, Tata Balanced Advantage FUnd) and expect a return of 10-12% over a horizon of 1.5 years. And invest the rest in midcap/smallcap equity funds which have portfolio investments in FMCG, Oil,Aviation and Gold related mutual funds, expecting returns of around 15-17% annualized over a horizon of 3 to 4 years.

SIP Strategy: Play safe by investing in big funds which have portfolios comprising of big, stable companies. Invest in large cap equity funds (Axis Focused 25, Axis bluechip fund, ICICI Prudential Value Discovery fund) over a horizon of 3 years and expect returns of minimum 10-12% annualized. Please comment on my strategy and any suggestions on which funds (& sectors to focus on) to be invested in for lumpsum and SIP based on the returns I am expecting, would be highly appreciated.

Comment: 10-12% from bonds? Wow! You must live in a very high inflation rate country.

Comment: Time in the market beats timing the market. If you have the money to invest now, do it now. Don't spread it out over three years.